# python mmap flush() doesn't work with ACCESS_COPY

Tags: python, mmap, flush

I'm trying to map a file with ACCESS_COPY mode. Then I write one char and flush, but flush() returns failure and changes are not wrote back to the file. Any ideas why? Thank you.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

import os, mmap

f = open('etc.test', 'r+b')

mapped = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY)
print mapped[0]
mapped[0] = 'R'
print mapped.flush()  <--- returns 0 (error on Windows)
mapped.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using mmap.ACCESS_COPY ? mmap.ACCESS_COPY is documented to not be able to write changes back to the file.

Comment: yes, I want to make changes in memory, and then write back to file. "Assignment to an ACCESS_COPY memory map affects memory but does not update the underlying file."  " flush([offset, size])

    Flushes changes made to the in-memory copy of a file back to disk."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found the answer:

Indeed, that's the intended behavior. From python source code:

```
    if (self->access == ACCESS_READ || self->access == ACCESS_COPY)
    return PyLong_FromLong(0);
```

So, it will return 0 if using ACCESS_COPY. This is normal, Windows API behaves this way, COW is used only in memory, and won't be flushed back.

Anyway, you could write all the data back with f.write()